# Independence of random variables in a Matlab simulation

Tags: matlab

I have some doubts on how to ensure independence of random variables in a Matlab simulation. Consider the following example:

```
T=400;
x=randi(3,T,1); %Tx1
w=randn(T,1); %Tx1
```

We know that, for `t=1,...,T`, `x(t)` is a draw from a `Unif([1,3])`. 
We can think of `x(t)` as the realisation of a random variable `X_t~Unif([1,3])` for `t=1,...,T` with
`(X_1,..., X_T)` mutually independent.

We know that, for `t=1,...,T`, `w(t)` is a draw from a `N(0,1)`. 
We can think of `w(t)` as the realisation of a random variable `W_t~N(0,1)` for `t=1,...,T` with `(W_1,..., W_T)` mutually independent.

**Question**: Suppose I want to ensure that, for each `t=1,...,T`, `W_t` is independent of `X_t`: do my steps above automatically ensure that and, if not, which modifications I should introduce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can as far as it is possible for pseudorandom numbers in general. But casting the pseduo part aside, all numbers come from the same number generator as mentioned [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/controlling-random-number-generation.html) in the documentation

> "Each time you call rand, randi, or randn, they draw a new value from their shared random number generator, and successive values can be treated as statistically independent. "

So if you say that the values `(X_1,..., X_T)` are mutually independent then the values `(X_1,..., X_2T)` are also mutually independent. In your example `(X_1,..., X_T)` are used for `x` while `(X_T+1,..., X_2T)` are used for `w`.

Comment: I have posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910705/understanding-how-pseudo-random-numbers-in-matlab-imply-statistical-independence, related to this but slightly more involved. Could you help me to sort it out if you have some time? Thanks