# Understanding how pseudo random numbers in Matlab imply statistical independence

Tags: matlab, random

Consider the following Matlab code in which I generate some data using pseudo random number generator.
I would like your help to understand "how" random are these numbers from a statistical point of view, in the terms I explain below.

I first set some parameters

```
%%%%%%%%Parameters
clear
rng default
Xsup=-1:6; 
Zsup=1:10; 
n_m=200; 
n_w=200; 
R=n_m;
```

Then I generate the data

```
%%%%%%%%Creation of data [XZ,etapair,zetapair,etasingle,zetasingle]

%Vector X of dimension n_mx1
idX=randi(size(Xsup,2),n_m,1); %n_mx1
X=Xsup(idX).'; %n_mx1

%Vector Z of dimension n_wx1
idZ=randi(size(Zsup,2),n_w,1); 
Z=Zsup(idZ).'; %n_wx1

%Combine X and Z in a matrix XZ of dimension (n_m*n_w)x2 
which lists all possible combinations of values in X and Z
[cX, cZ] = ndgrid(X,Z);
XZ = [cX(:), cZ(:)]; %(n_m*n_w)x2

%Vector etapair of dimension (n_m*n_w)x1
etapair=randn(n_m*n_w,1); %(n_m*n_w)x1

%Vector zetapair of dimension (n_m*n_w)x1
zetapair=randn(n_m*n_w,1); %(n_m*n_w)x1

%Vector etasingle of dimension (n_m*n_w)x1
etasingle=max(randn(n_m,R),[],2); %n_mx1 
etasingle=repmat(etasingle, n_w,1); %(n_m*n_w)x1

%Vector zetasingle of dimension (n_m*n_w)x1
zetasingle=max(randn(n_w,R),[],2); %n_wx1
zetasingle=kron(zetasingle, ones(n_m,1)); %(n_m*n_w)x1
```

Let me now translate these draws into statistical terms:

For `t=1,...,n_w*n_m`, `X(t)` can be thought as a realisation of a random variable `X_t`

For `t=1,...,n_w*n_m`, `Z(t)` can be thought as a realisation of a random variable `Z_t`

For `t=1,...,n_w*n_m`, `etapair(t)` can be thought as a realisation of a random variable `E_t`

For `t=1,...,n_w*n_m`, `zetapair(t)` can be thought as a realisation of a random variable `Q_t`

For `t=1,...,n_w*n_m`, `etasingle(t)` can be thought as a realisation of a random variable `Y_t`

For `t=1,...,n_w*n_m`, `zetasingle(t)` can be thought as a realisation of a random variable `S_t`

My belief was that the pseudo random number generator in Matlab allows to claim that
`(X_1,X_2,..., Z_1,Z_2,...,E_1,E_2,..., Q_1,Q_2...,Y_1,Y_2,...,S_1,S_2,...)` are mutually independent
as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48888423/independence-of-random-variables-in-a-matlab-simulation)

As a check of this hypothetical claim, I define `W_t:=-E_t-Q_t+Y_t+S_t` and empirically compute `Pr(W_t<=1|X_t=5, Z_t=1)`

If mutual independence holds, then `Pr(W_t<=1|X_t=5, Z_t=1)=Pr(W_t<=1)` and their empirical counterparts below, named `option1` and `option2`, should be ALMOST the same.

```
%option 1
num1=zeros(n_m*n_w,1);
for h=1:n_m*n_w
    if -etapair(h)-zetapair(h)+etasingle(h)+zetasingle(h)<=1 && XZ(h,1)==5 && XZ(h,2)==1
        num1(h)=1;
    end
end
den1=zeros(n_m*n_w,1);
for h=1:n_m*n_w
    if  XZ(h,1)==5 && XZ(h,2)==1
        den1(h)=1;
    end
end
option1=sum(num1)/sum(den1);

%option 2
num2=zeros(n_m*n_w,1);
for h=1:n_m*n_w
    if -etapair(h)-zetapair(h)+etasingle(h)+zetasingle(h)<=1 
        num2(h)=1;
    end
end
option2=sum(num2)/(n_m*n_w);
```

**Question**: the difference between `option1` (=0.0021) and `option2` (=0.0012) is referred to the "ALMOST" or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: It's unclear what your actual question is here, as you're either talking about some detailed statistical question (as suggested by Sardar) or you seem to be asking "given all these *random* variables generated by MATLAB, are they definitely independent?", which just harks back to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48888423/3978545) where the answer was "yes". Are you expecting a short "you are correct" here, or a discussion about how MATLAB handles random number generation?

Comment: @Wolfie Firstly, I have shortened my question (before I was doing a double random step) to make it easier. Secondly, I expect a discussion on why the statistical independence claimed by Matlab does not seem to hold when I simply compare conditional probabilities with unconditional probabilities.

Comment: You sound quite defensive? I was just trying to clarify the question so that I could provide an accurate answer...

Answer (score 0):

By the very nature of observing *random* events, you cannot guarantee theoretically accurate results for a give empirical trial.

You have set `rng default` at the start of your script, which means you will always get the same result (`option1 = 0.0021`, `option2 = 0.0012`).

Running your script many times and averaging the results, we should approach theoretical accuracy.

```
kk = 10000;
option1 = zeros(kk, 1);
option2 = zeros(kk, 1);
for ii = 1:kk
    % No need to use 'clear' here. If you were concerned 
    % for some reason, you could use 'clearvars -except kk option1 option2 ii'
    % do not use 'rng default'. Use 'rng shuffle' if anything, but not necessary
    Xsup = -1:6;
    % ... all your other code
    % replace 'option1=...' with 'option1(ii)=...'
    % replace 'option2=...' with 'option2(ii)=...'  
end
fprintf('Results:\nMean option1 = %f\nMean option2 = %f\n', mean(option1), mean(option2));
```

Results:

```
>> Mean option1 = 0.001461
>> Mean option2 = 0.001458
```

We can see these are the same to some degree of accuracy, which can be arbitrarily high if we run X trials (for large enough X). This is as expected for independent variables.

---

Note, if you have the parallel computing toolbox, this `for` loop can easily be swapped for a `parfor`, and you can run trials many times faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Are you saying that the `n_m*n_w` replications are not taking that "need of replication-averaging" into account? In other words: to have theoretical accuracy, I would need to draw each one of the `n_w*n_w` rows separately in a loop?

Comment: You can never achieve perfect theoretical statistical results of this test from a single trial, unless by luck. I'm showing that, with enough trials, we can prove that MATLAB's random number generator produces independent values.

Comment: @user3285148 It means each time you call those values since you last shuffled the random number generator. When you start MATLAB, this is shuffled to `'default'`. If you want to start from a new point each time you open MATLAB, simply call `rng shuffle` in your startup script